# React/SCSS/GatsbyJS - Minimize all class names

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gatsby, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` in my `GatsbyJS` project in which I use `SCSS` for styling (a mix of bootstrap classes + some of my own). I want to minimize and obfuscate all the `classNames` in the production build of my site but I'm having issues achieving it.

I've tried a number of `GatbsyJS` plugins to achieve this but most seem to assume usage of `CSS` modules which I don't think I can do when using `react-bootstrap` (or other packages) since I can't control the approach to specifying `classNames` they use.

I've also explored just importing the minified `CSS` for `react-bootstrap` and using that directly, however that doesn't really help and won't work for my setup as I need the ability to override `SCSS` variables.

In the past I've utilised `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` to achieve what I'm after, however I've tried customising the `webpack` config for `GatsbyJS` without any success.

```
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin")

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
    actions,
  }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            ],
        }
    })
  }
```

Any ideas on how I can continue using `SCSS` throughout my project but end up with minimized `classNames` in my production build would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t configured this particular plugin or needed to solve for the problem you are encountering with Sass, but perhaps this plugin will work for you after all if you configure it like this (which is what I do for other Webpack plugins in Gatsby):

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a go but sadly no luck.